# JSON POST Request receiving from server side using Php from HttpClient in Android?

Tags: java, php, android, json

I'm sending a JSON request from Android app using `HttpClient` to Server using `PHP` to receive the request.
My codes:

In `MainActivity.java` below is my `AsyncTask`:

```
class AsyncT extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("https://test1.intuitionsoftwares.com/paytm/name2.php");

            try {

                JSONObject jsonobj = new JSONObject();
                jsonobj.put("name", "Suraj");
                jsonobj.put("age", "25");

                List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("req", jsonobj.toString()));

                Log.e("mainToPost", "mainToPost" + nameValuePairs.toString());

               httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                InputStream inputStream = response.getEntity().getContent();
                InputStreamToStringExample str = new InputStreamToStringExample();
                responseServer = str.getStringFromInputStream(inputStream);
                Log.e("response", "response -----" + responseServer);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);    
            txt.setText(responseServer);
        }
    }
```

And My `Php` Codes are below (`name2.php`):

```
    <?php
header('Content-Type: application/json');
$content = trim(file_get_contents("php://input")); 
$get = json_decode($content);
//Process the JSON.
$name = $get->name;
$age = $get->age;
$myJSON = json_encode($get);
//echo json_encode($name);
echo $name;
echo $age;
?>
```

So, I need to display the `JSON` I'm sending to the `link: https://test1.intuitionsoftwares.com/paytm/name2.php`.

Any help with my `php` or `Android` code rectification would be appreciated.

Comment: what error you got ?

Comment: i think you can't see them in the actual page  . log them to  the log file or add them in the database

Comment: Nothing at all. From Log Cat I can see Success...for Json Sending. But in that link I see nothing. Also, Using this code--->  if(!is_array($decoded)){
/throw new Exception('Received content contained invalid JSON!');
}, I get the exception with Fatal: Received content contained invalid JSON!

Comment: in your php , why you use : $get = json_decode(stripslashes($_POST['req'])); 
 instead of
$get = json_decode($content);

Comment: @MOHAMMEDYASSINEChabli: Can you check the updated php code now. I just made changes as you said. Still it shows nothing.

Comment: i'm testing your service from the url :
https://test1.intuitionsoftwares.com/paytm/name2.php
with post data as :
{
  "name":"denba",
  "age" : "23"
}
The response is :

Unexpected token VALUE(null) at position 36.

Comment: Yes, I'm too getting Null, So, Do you recomend me to check my Java code whether its sending no JSON data to server ?

Comment: i have tested now, and getting good response . did the problem still now ?

Comment: post the sample data u are sending or receiving

Comment: @MarvinCollins Hi, I am sending simple name and Age which you can see in the AsyncTask---> JSONObject jsonobj = new JSONObject();
                jsonobj.put("name", "Suraj");
                jsonobj.put("age", "25");

Comment: @MOHAMMEDYASSINEChabli Yes, Still I cant get the data displayed.

Answer (score 0):

change code php from `$get = json_decode($content);`

became this code `$get = json_decode(stripslashes($_POST['req']));`